# how can i retrieve the caller's path?

Tags: php

in a script i call another class with:

```
Factory::folder();
```

but when i specify...

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

...i get the library's path, not the caller's.

how can i have the caller's path?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getfilename.php). To be more specific, it's method [getFileName()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getfilename.php).

Comment: is that class built-in into php?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's not documented very well.

Answer (score 1):

Do this,

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();

echo $trace[1]['file']
```

You can even go back further.

Comment: but this is a good in production? sounds only for development

Comment: Yes. It's good in production. Whenever you have a PHP error in production, the function is invoked to print the backtrace.

Comment: No. It's only good for debugging in production - for logging etc. But definitely not for dynamic factories.